# Triggering Visceral Attack

Tags: bloodborne

After finally getting a decent understanding of Bloodborne's mechanics, I found out how to pull off [visceral attacks](http://bloodborne.wikidot.com/visceral-attack) (similar to Dark Souls' riposte/parry mechanic). However, I only seem to trigger these when I interrupt an enemy's attack with a well-timed shot from my Hunter Pistol. Is it possible to trigger a visceral attack using only your primary weapon? Are there any other ways to trigger these attacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hitting an enemy in the back with a fully-charged R2 attack will stagger them and allow for a visceral attack. Some large enemies and bosses are immune to this backstab, but most have weak points that you can focus on that'll eventually put them into a vulnerable state.